# Is the order of the ".on" functions important in D3?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a circle whose color should change to red when clicked on. I also want to invoke a second function: "second click function" on the same click.

My problem is, at this stage only the second ".on" exectues, but ignores the first ".on", that means, the color does not change.

```
 var newcircle = svg.append("circle")
     .data(nodes)
     .attr("cx", 33)
     .attr("cy", 44)
     .attr("r", 33)
     .style("fill", "red")   
     .on("click", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");})   
     .on("click", function(d) { "second click function" } )
```

If I change the order of the ".on" functions into this:

```
 var newcircle = svg.append("circle")
     .data(nodes)
     .attr("cx", 33)
     .attr("cy", 44)
     .attr("r", 33)
     .style("fill", "red")        
     .on("click", function(d) { "second click function" })  
     .on("click", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");})
```

then it only changes the color, but not doing the "second click function".

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_on explains,

> If an event listener was previously registered for the same typename
>   on a selected element, the old listener is removed before the new
>   listener is added.

But it's simple to solve the problem; just add all the logic into one function.

```
.on("click", function(){
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");
  "second click function"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You are binding an event of "click" to en element using the `.on` function.  By adding a second definition of the event, the previous one is overwritten for that element.

To execute another function within your event handler, just invoke it within the function body of your event callback:

```
function resetCircleColor(ref){
  // do whatever you need to here, like set the fill color to green:
  // this assumes you are passing the correct reference to the circle
  // you want to change as the paramter 'ref'
  ref.style("fill", "red");
}
var newcircle = svg.append("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .attr("cx", 33)
  .attr("cy", 44)
  .attr("r", 33)
  .style("fill", "red")

.on("click", function(){
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "green");
  resetCircleColor(circleref);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much, guys! One question: i got 2 circles and i want that when i click on circle a, it turns red and when i click on circle b, this circle truns red, but circle a will go back on his original color...do i need a toggle function for this?

Comment: Check out my updated answer.  I call a function `resetCircleColor` inside the _click_ event that accept the reference of a circle as the first argument.  You can get this reference using jquery or vanilla javascript `getElementById`